# python multiprocessing - run logic when process terminates

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When using Python multiprocessing, what is the proper way to ensure code will run to cleanup whenever a process exits (both cleanly or on fatal error.)

If I am writing my processes as inheriting from the `Process` object, should I put this functionality in the `__del__` method of the object?  I tried putting simple log statements into `terminate`, but it doesn't seem to execute when the script receives a SIGHUP or `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html)-handlers, which are pretty reliable in my experience.

Comment: Yeah -- IIRC, `atexit` doesn't handle signals though.

Comment: @senderie: you are right. signals not handled by python, will bypass the atexit-handler. I guess it is possible to write signal-handlers for those cases. The docs have all the smallprint.